# Jira Rest Api Nested MaxResults (get all worklog within time period)

Tags: .net, jira

I am writing an app that should get all the worklogs within specified time period for all jira users. I am using jira rest api to get these information, however i have a problem with nested maxResults for each issue that i get.
This is the url i am using:

**https://"your_jira_home"/rest/api/latest/search?jql=key in workedIssues("2014/12/8","2014/12/12","jira-users")&fields=worklog&maxResults=-1**

This will return all issues (up to 1000) within specified time range for all users and their worklogs, but it will return 20 worklogs per issue, and i need more (all of them).

{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 1000,
    "total": 98,
    "issues": [{
        "expand": "operations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields",
        "id": "",
        "self": "",
        "key": "",
        "fields": {
            "worklog": {
                "startAt": 0,
                **"maxResults": 20,**
                "total": 1,...

Is there a way to specify nested max results (the one in "worklog")?

Another way for getting worklogs would be  using this url:

**https://"your_jira_home"/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=your_project_name&fields=worklog&maxResults=-1**

but the same problem occurs with nested maxResults.

I am developing app in .NET, and i am not using any plugin for jira yet.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you got an answer for this?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to change the startAt or the maxResults of the nested worklog results in the current Jira API version 2.

To get all the worklog records of an issue you need to use:
**https://"your_jira_home"/rest/api/latest/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/worklog**

There isn't a way to query multiple issues who have more than 20 worklog records and get all the worklog records.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/327748/how-do-i-set-maxresults-for-work-logs